# Will sklearn lasso automatically run in parallel?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, slurm

I want to run a lasso regression using `sklearn.linear_model.Lasso` module in parallel.

The bash script I use for submitting the job is something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --partition=the_partition
#SBATCH --nodes=2
#SBATCH --ntasks=56
python lasso_script.py
```

The relevant part in `lasso_script.py` is

```
Lasso(alpha=0.1, copy_X=True, fit_intercept=True, max_iter=1000,
  normalize=False, positive=False, precompute=False, random_state=None,
  selection='cyclic', tol=0.0001, warm_start=False)
```

If I submit the job by using the script will the lasso regression automatically run in parallel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It does not run on multiple threads I believe

Comment: Do you have any source or concrete reason for your belief?

Comment: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/linear_model/coordinate_descent.py

Answer (score 1):

No, it doesn't run on parallel thread. Instead you could mention n_jobs= -1 (-1 utilises all the cores in CPU  by default)